# Layout of homepage looks good on localhost but not live?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, gatsby, netlify

When I publish my site (gatsby site via Netlify) the layout of the live homepage is broken however the localhost homepage is not.

It gets weirder. When navigating to another page on the live site the layout problems are fixed, they are also fixed when I return to the homepage, however, the layout problems return when the page is refreshed.

Screenshot of localhost (correct):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgpgz.jpg

Screenshot of live site (broken):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eCyJ.jpg

I checked developer tools for errors but there were none. I can't for the life of me get a clue on what's going on. Any help?

If it helps my repo is: https://github.com/ColinTS/MountainHouse and my live url is [www.singlefintaghazout.com](https://www.singlefintaghazout.com)

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you are preventing and blocking React's rehydration, that's why it gets this odd behavior when moving backward and forward (navigating to the site), depending on whether the rehydrate process has succeeded or not.

This happens when you point directly to the DOM instead of the virtual DOM (vDOM) that React's manipulating, or in other words, pointing to the DOM outside React's ecosystem and lifecycle.

In your [`layout.js` (line 31)](https://github.com/ColinTS/MountainHouse/blob/master/src/components/layout.js#L31) you have:

```
  <Helmet>
    <script type="text/javascript">{`window.$crisp=[];window.CRISP_WEBSITE_ID="3f96f73e-9f2d-40ac-81d8-12ba7e9462b4";(function(){d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.src="https://client.crisp.chat/l.js";s.async=1;d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})();`}</script>
  </Helmet>
```

Which, as you can see, is pointing to the `window` and to the DOM elements (`getElementsByTagName`, `document`, etc).

Try removing that `<Helmet>` to be 100% that this is causing your rehydration issues and to fix it, you can try to [customize your `html.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/) output. Run:

```
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

*Note: or copy the `default-html.js` in `.cache` folder and rename it to `html.js`*

There, you can add your script in the resulting `html.js` file, placed in the `<head>`.

There are other alternative methods to insert scripts to the `<head>` if this doesn't work, but the idea is to remove the DOM pointing elements from a React component.

P.S: building your site locally (`gatsby build && gatsby serve`) will reproduce the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your indepth answer Ferran! Unfortunately, commenting out this line did not fix it was actually working fine with this script before. Do you have any other ideas of what it could be?

Comment: You should have any other code where you point to the DOM (`window`)